# htaccess Rewrite Rule for subdomain to page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, rule

Currently I have a page residing at:

```
http://www.example.com/site/page
```

In my htaccess I have the current rule:

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ retailer.php?linklabel=$1 [QSA]
```

What would the rule look like to have the URL for that page become it's own subdomain:

```
http://page.example.com
```

Thanks for any help!!

So far I have tried the following rule which hasn't worked:

```
RewriteRule http://(.*)$.example.com retailer.php?linklabel=$1 [QSA]
```

Maybe I need to do something in cpanel first regarding a wildcard subdomain? I'm not too sure...

Comment: @Yazmat: I've editted my original post. Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Very clear question. Exactly what I'm looking for. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ retailer.php?linklabel=%1 [L,QSA]
```

You can't match against the host in a `RewriteRule`, so you'll need to do it against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` var in a `RewriteCond`, then use the **`%1`** backreference to get that match.

This will currently only match against URI's that are exactly `/`. So it won't match against `http://page.example.com/something` unless you change the regular express at from `^$` to `^something$`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the actual url right now looks like:

http://www.example.com/site/page.com

So then the subdomain is trying to be:

http://page.com.example.com

Will the extra "." in the subdomain mess things up?

The solution you posted isn't working currently. Thanks!

Comment: @PaperChase Yes, the extra dot will not be matched against, just change the `([^.]+)\.example.com$` to `(.+?)\.example.com$`

Comment: @PaperChase Like I mentioned in the last paragraph of the answer, you'll need to taily the rule's expression to match whatever it is that you're doing (which you didn't mention in your question at first), so if it's `/site/page.com`, the `/site/` **must** be represented in the regular expression. `^$` therefore becomes `^site/?$`

Comment: I'm not following sorry. Can you help me create a rule specific to a certain page? I want http://jcwhitney.example.com to display the contents of http://www.example.com/retailer.php?linklabel=jcwhitney.com. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @PaperChase Not sure what problem you're having, but those rules in my answer placed in a blank htaccess file on a vanilla apache install works just fine for `http://jcwhitney.example.com/` to `http://www.example.com/retailer.php?linklabel=jcwhitney.com`:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/PsIWQ.png

Comment: @PaperChase unless you've somehow neglected to mention that they're on different servers.

Comment: They are on the same server. But are you sure it is working correctly? The subdomain is called "jcwhitney" but in the query string linklabel is "jcwhitney.com"

Comment: I don't see in the rewrite rule how you have added the ".com" to the query string. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @PaperChase where does .com get extracted from? Do you just arbitrarily add it to the end? If so just do `retailer.php?linklabel=%1.com` Having the subdomain end with a `.com` wasn't even in your question.

Comment: Yea I've done what you have said but it is still not working. Do I have to set up a wildcard domain in cpanel first?

Comment: @PaperChase that's the first thing you need to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15398/discussion-between-paperchase-and-jon-lin)

Comment: Jon, looks like I'm having an issue incorporating your rule with another rule in my htaccess. It is there to add "www." to any url on my site. I have it to avoid duplication issues. Here is the rule that is conflicint and causing my main site not to load. Any way to incorporate it? 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* retailer.php?linklabel=%1 [L,QSA]
```