# Redirect using .htaccess so that users appear as a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been using `.htaccess` for few redirects, I am having a hard time finding any solution for a new redirect I want.

I have users on my site and urls look like:

```
http://www.domain.com/users.php?user=username
```

Is it possible to rewrite it using htaccess so that it appears:

```
http://username.domain.com
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you will probably need to set up a wildcard entry in your DNS to direct any subdomain to your IP.

Comment: Just to clarify, did you want the URL to look like `http://username.domain.com` but to really be accessing a file at `http://www.domain.com/users.php?user=username`? Or did you want to redirect urls to the subdomain style?

Comment: I want just the url to look like `http://username.domain.com` and it access `http://www.domain.com/users.php?user=username`

Comment: Gotcha. You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976475/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-subdomain-to-page

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

`RewriteRule ^users.php?user=(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/ [R,L]`

Comment: will this redirect or it will just rewrite the url and will access the actual file?

Comment: It will access the actual file, but the other answer is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've set it up so that all subdomains of `domain.com` point to the *same document root* as `domain.com` then you can do this with a single htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect to user's subdomain when a specific request is made to users.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /users\.php\?user=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.domain.com/ [L,R=301]

# internally rewrite the user's subdomain to users.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /users\.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: there is no subdomain actually, I just want the url to look like subdomain

Comment: @Ankush That's not how this works. You can't arbitrarily display whatever you want on the browser's location bar, in fact, browser makers spend quite a bit of effort to make sure people can't hack this.

Comment: ok basically I want whenever a user creates account on my site, he will be give a personalized page like `http://user.domain.com` is there any way of doing it?

Comment: @Ankush not without having subdomains

Comment: ok thank you for your suggestion, is there a possible way to create subdomains automatically when someone registers?