# Using .htaccess to create user subdomains (which convert to/from URI data)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP application that allows users to register with a company and a user (user is automatically associated with that company). All data is store in a MySQL DB.

I want to turn `[company_name].domain.com` into `domain.com/app?company_id=[company_id]` without affecting stylsheets/js/subfolders/etc and I need to retain the ability to use further GET requests within the application.

I understand the basics of .htaccess but am unable to find a solution for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What actually do you mean with "without affecting stylsheets/js/subfolders/etc"? Should the CSS etc still be accessibly via company.domain.com?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976475/htaccess-rewrite-rule-for-subdomain-to-page